# C++ Area of a Rectangle Error Checking Function

Tags: error-handling

Below is the code I have for a program in which the user is asked to input the length and width, and the area is then calculated and the length, width, and area displayed.

I am trying to incorporate the error checking function at the bottom of the code for the user inputs so that if the user types in something that is not a number, `Invalid input. Try again:` is displayed.

I have looked on several forum posts and have been at this for hours so I would appreciate any help trying to make the error checking function work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

// Write the prototypes for the getLength,
// getWidth, getArea, and displayData
// functions here.

double getLength();
double getWidth();
double getArea(double, double);
void displayData(double, double, double);
double error(double);

int main()
{
   double len,    // The rectangle's length
          wid,     // The rectangle's width
          ar;      // The rectangle's area

   // Get the rectangle's length.
   len = getLength();

   // Get the rectangle's width.
   wid = getWidth();

   // Get the rectangle's area.
   ar = getArea(len, wid);

   // Display the rectangle's data.
   displayData(len, wid, ar);

   return 0;
}

double getLength ()
{

    double length;
    cout << "Please enter the length of the rectangle:" << endl;
    cin >> length;
    error (length);
    return length;

}

double getWidth ()
{

    double width;
    cout << "Please enter the width of the rectangle:" << endl;
    cin >> width;
    error (width);
    return width;

}

double getArea (double length, double width)
{

    double area;
    area = length*width;
    return area;

}

void displayData(double length, double width, double area)
{

    cout << "The length is: " << length << endl;
    cout << "The width is: " << width << endl;
    cout << "The area is: " << area << endl;

}

double error(double x)
{

   while(!(cin>>x))

   {
       cin.clear();
       cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

       cout << "Invalid input. Try again: " << endl;
       cin>>x;

       return x;
    }
   cout << "You entered: " << x << endl;

   return x;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a console app so you are probably using scanf()? In that case you should check the return value from scanf() to see how many items were scanned and formatted:
int result = scanf("%f", &length);

If result is zero, then the user typed in a value that could not be interpreted as a double. You don't know why it was invalid and you can't determine if the user typed in garbage after the double, but it's better than nothing.

You can do much more validation if you read a string and then parse it yourself or look for third-party code that will parse it for you.